# add figure in the beginning of page and entering the sections

Tags: formatting

I want to create a latex page similar to this. How can I insert a figure at the beginning of the page and centre my subsection. I am trying to modify the article class of latex.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is room for it you can put a picture above the title after you have set the title. There are some different ways to put stuff on the page without influencing the rest of the material. The easiest for this case I would say is to use a tikz picture with `overlay` option. (You need to compile twice to get the picture on the right place).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\title{Paper title}
\author{Author list}
\maketitle
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[below=20mm] at (current page.north){\includegraphics[width=40mm]{example-image-a}};
%%%
\begin{abstract}
  Paper abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Background}
Problem background: Why is this interesting?

\section{Methodology}
What method have you used?

\end{document}
```

[image]